# Node.js threw an error “cannot find module ’webpack’ ”

Tags: reactjs, redux

I downloaded a project by a book writer  from internet. If I copied the resource code into my project created by default redux framework “create-react-app”, it works. 
But when I changed the default directory of node.js to the demo directory , it threw an error as ”Cannot find module ‘we pack ’”, no matter I installed webpack using “npm install —global webpack” or “npm install webpack”,  it still threw the same error when I start the demo.
What’s wrong with my development environment, Please tell me what happened?

Comment: Did you install all dependencies? `npm install`

Comment: I’m a new React learner, so where can I find all dependencies ? And why it report the same error after installed ‘webpack’?

Comment: @Biao You can find them in your `package.json` .. You don't need to worry about them, just issue a `npm install` command from your command line.

Comment: @David R If I have to use the command ‘cd’ to change my project directory and then use ‘npm install’ to install all dependencies?

Comment: Navigate to the path where your `package.json` is residing and issue a `npm install` ?

Comment: @David R Thanks a lot , because I’m using my  mobile phone on a busine trip. I will try your instructions when I got back home.

Comment: Cheers! @Biao :-)

Comment: @David R It works for me! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that it is working now!  :-)